# How to make predictions with libmf using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement libmf library in python. I tried with the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from libmf import mf

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6], 
              [7, 8, 9]])

n = X.shape[0]
p = X.shape[1]
k = 2
eta = 0.1
nr_iters = 1000

Y = np.zeros((n*p, 3))
r = 1
for i in np.arange(1, n+1):
    for j in np.arange(1, p+1):
        Y[r-1, :] = np.array([i, j, X[i-1, j-1]])
        r = r + 1
```

libmf takes a matrix whose rows are $(i, \ j, \ value)$ of the original matrix we want to factorize.

I can use the fit method:

```
engine = mf.MF(fun = 0, k = k, eta = eta, nr_iters = nr_iters, quiet = False, 
               lambda_p2 = 0, lambda_q2 = 0)
engine.fit(Y)
```

But when I try to use the predict method I get an error:

```
engine.predict(Y[[1-1, 2-1],:])
raise ValueError("must be sparse array of shape (n, {0})", width)

ValueError: ('must be sparse array of shape (n, {0})', 2)
```

How should the matrix be given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/PorkShoulderHolder/python-libmf/blob/master/libmf/mf.py), it ask for a (n,2) numpy array, not very well documented, but I guess you don't need the column of values:

```
def predict(self, X):
        """
        assuming we have already run the fit method, predict the values at certain indices of the data matrix
        :param X: (n, 2) shaped numpy array
        :return: numpy array of length n
        """
        if self.model is None:
            return LookupError("no model data is saved, try running model.mf_fit(...) first")
        ensure_width(X, 2)
        nnx = X.shape[0]
        out = np.zeros(nnx)
        out = out.astype(np.float32)
        X = X.astype(np.float32)
        X_p = X.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
        nnx_p = ctypes.c_int(nnx)
        mf.pred_model_interface(nnx_p, X_p, ctypes.c_void_p(out.ctypes.data), ctypes.byref(self.model))
        return out
```

Most likely you can do:

```
engine.predict(Y[[1-1, 2-1],:2])
array([0.97788346, 1.9762692 ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: That seems very reasonable. The fit method expects the non zero elements of a large sparse matrix and it factorizes it, so I think you're right. However, I had the idea that we can train the model with a training matrix and we should predict for a test matrix, so in this case I don't know what the relationship between predicting the value for $(i, \ j)$ and a test matrix is.

Comment: yes i agree with you it's a bit odd, it seems like the predict function in this case is just for retrieving the predictions. not very familiar with this package.. most likely you have to ask the authors how to get it to predict new data

Comment: Hi, I have recently tried to use this package but could not figure out how to factor $X$ into $WH$. Could you please have a look at my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555923/how-to-run-parallel-nmf-with-package-libmf)?